# US Government Export Approval for TI chip

Tags: integrated-circuit, texas-instruments

I hope this isn't off-topic since I think it's a general issue that applies to many ICs.

I'm looking into buying a TI battery charger chip, but the datasheet alone seems to be restricted by the "U.S. Government export approval". Does that mean even buying a few samples would need such an approval?

The form for datasheet on the TI site asks for a name, an email address and an affiliation. How does the US Government conduct a meaningful assessment given the unreliable data? There's no verification involved but it takes 1-2 business days for processing.

To buy larger quantities, would one need special documents?

Thanks

Comment: At one stage my company used a lot of restricted resistors. We eventually got a personal visit from a US agency, and their security team, to verify that we were using them in our products (not shipping them to a banned country). So they do look at the data they collect! See also [this story](https://m.fbi.gov/#https://www.fbi.gov/minneapolis/press-releases/2011/five-individuals-indicted-in-a-fraud-conspiracy-involving-exports-to-iran-of-u.s.-components-later-found-in-bombs-in-iraq) for a very relevant example.

Comment: Interesting. Did you need an approval when you made the purchases though? What quantity did you use?

Comment: There is the theory that when you list all restricted items, you have the combined BOM of all us nuclear devices...

Comment: Wikipedia has a writeup here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Export_Administration_Regulations  This is a serious legal requirement for US companies; we can get fined if we don't have ECCN documentation for everything we ship.

Comment: The part may have an ECCN number etc, but what is required from the buyer if they purchase large quantities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not affiliated with TI, so I can't do more than speculate into their reasoning, a vendor is required to perform the due diligence necessary to make sure that parts they ship won't end up in a sanctioned nation.  The [Overview of U.S. Export Control System](http://www.state.gov/strategictrade/overview/) has a few guidelines for exporters along with a few common-sense checks that the exporter should perform, all of which sound similar to the data TI collects.

> Applying common sense is essential in weeding out potentially problematic transfers. Alarms should sound if:
>
> A customer or agent -
>
> Is reluctant to provide end-use/user information
>
> Is willing to pay cash for high-value shipments
>
> Has little background or history in the relevant business
>
> Appears unfamiliar with the product or its use
>
> Declines normal warranty/service/installation
>
> Orders products/quantities incompatible with the relevant business
>
> Provides vague delivery dates or locations

By providing that information early, often, and consistently, one gives TI plausible deniability should a customer order a bulk shipment of parts and forward it to North Korea, or something along those lines.